# ASP .NET Core Web API route dot in url causes 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem of url routing in ASP.NET Core web api. When the URL contins dot (.) it returns 404 not found. For example,

> http://localhost:9030/api/test/109/fake@email.com

The code that doesn't work with email but work with no dot

```
public class TestController : Controller{
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        //whatever
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/{name:alpha}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id, string name)
    {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

However, this works

> http://localhost:9030/api/test/getbyname/109/fake@email.com

```
public class TestController : Controller{
{
    [HttpGet("GetById/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        //whatever
    }

    [HttpGet("GetByName/{id}/{name}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id, string name)
    {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

How to solve that problem?

Comment: `fake@email.com` would not be valid regardless. Did you forget to url encode the `@`? https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: No problem with @. The problem is dot (.). I'm using IIS 8.5

Comment: It may _work_, but you shouldn't be passing `@` like that. You should url encode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the

```
[Route("{id:int}/{name:alpha}")]
```

You are saying only accept alphabet characters which means a-z and A-Z not including any special characters. you are best using a regex to validate if it is always an email address.

try this

```
[Route("{id:int}/{name}")]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. This is the complete explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and this is for custom constraints sample https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-routing-constraint/