# Controller route not found if it contains a version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having issues when trying to route to a Controller when it is included via a external project. The controller in question works fine when included directly in the project or from the external project ONLY when the version field is removed from the route. The controller is defined as below.

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/devices")]
[Authorize(Roles = UserConst.PermissionGroup.Admin)]
public class DeviceManagementController : ControllerBase{...}
```

Changing the route to the below works correctly

```
[Route("api/devices")]
```

Changing the route to the below fails the same way as including it through `{version:apiVersion}`

```
[Route("api/v1.0/devices")]
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong? With any version info the server just seems to return the default Index page which is the fallback when a controller cannot be found.

Startup.cs code for adding Api versioning

```
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.DefaultApiVersion =
      new ApiVersion(1, 0);
   config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
   config.ReportApiVersions = true;
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021924/asp-net-core-web-api-route-dot-in-url-causes-404-not-found
Maybe the same? As in, I think the "." is the problem

Comment: Im not sure though as it works for other controllers and only failed when moved to an external assembley?

Comment: What url are you using?

Comment: @JohnH I can confirm it is an application part. .net core 5.0 does this automatically and the route is resolved fine if it doesn't included the version

Comment: @Serge /api/v1.0/devices is the URL which has worked fine in the past but no doesn't since it has been moved to external.

Comment: Is this [Route("api/devices")] working at external?

Comment: @JamesMoore can you give the full url pls? I guess you have more then one action and you can't use one route for all

Comment: @Serge yes it only breaks when I add the version part(either manually or resolved)

Comment: @JamesMoore  Since 1.0 is a default vesion what if you just using  ... /api/devices url? If it is working?  if it is working,  Can you change version to  [ApiVersion("2.0")] and try again?

Comment: @Serge couldn't resolve if I try just /api/devices.

Comment: @JamesMoore I am asking you again please post the real action, not just a controller and url you are using.

Comment: @Serge I have a single method which is [HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> GetDevices(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some testing.

Af first I added    [Route("api/devices")] to your controller attributes

```
[ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/devices")]
    [Route("api/devices")]
    public class DeviceManagementController : ControllerBase
```

and found that url  .../api/v1.0/devices works properly.

After this I tryed to use just .../api/devices url.

1. It was working properly with [ApiVersion("1.0")] attribute
2. It issued a wrong version error when I changed attribute to [ApiVersion("2.0")]

so everything was working as it was expected.

Summary:

I recommend you to add [Route("api/devices")] and try  to use.../api/devices url as a workaround for now, till you find out something better.

Comment: Thanks for this help Serge. It at least pointed me to the right direction and it turned out that caching was causing the old page to be loaded! Deleting the cache allowed me to get the api/version route working.

Comment: You are very welcome!